# Mongo DB bindIp configuration

Tags: mongodb

In the mongodb config file, what are the IP adresses which are passed in bindIP option
Are they the IP adresses of remote server which have to provided access to mongo database server or The IP addresses and/or full Unix domain socket paths on which mongod should listen for client connections.

Answer (score 1):

From the [net.bindIp section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) of the documentation page:

> The hostnames and/or IP addresses and/or full Unix domain socket paths on which mongos and mongod should listen for client connections.

Thus it is the server's IP addresses on which the `mongod` process should be listening to for incoming connections.

Note that in MongoDB versions 3.6 and later, this parameter has a default value of `127.0.0.1` (localhost).